# What types of healing does Aspect of Healing affect?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, prestige-class

The Singer of Concordance Prestige Class has a class feature that reads

> Aspect of Healing (Su): At 6th level, you become able to call upon your sphere's aspect of healing. This aspect is always active while you are conscious (and the effect moves with you), but not if you are unconscious or dead. Any healing performed within 10 feet of you (and any healing you initiate) cures an additional 1d8 points.
>   Undead within 10 feet of you that are dealt damage by a cure spell take an additional 1d8 points of damage.

I was wondering, what types of healing are affected by this? It specifically mentions cure spells in regards to damaging undead, but it doesn't mention that anywhere else. Are potions affected? Is Fast-Healing affected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The supernatural ability aspect of healing possessed by the prestige class Singer of Concordance (*Races of the Dragon* 91-6) *is* unclear as to how it's supposed to function. No errata nor Sage Advice discusses the ability. The DM must rule what, exactly, the aspect of healing affects.

#### House Rules

However, were a Singer of Concordance present in my campaign, unless a compelling case was made otherwise, I'd likely rule that to benefit from the aspect of healing, the healing must be *performed*—that is, a creature must have taken some kind of action for the aspect's effect to be realized. Hence, I'd allow a creature that, for example, took a standard action to drink a *potion of cure light wounds* to benefit from the aspect as I would a creature that took a swift action to activate a *cloak of predatory vigor* (*MIC* 87), but I would disallow the benefit to extend to, for example, a creature possessing a natural, constant source of [fast healing](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#fastHealing).<sup>1</sup>

In the case of spells like the 1st-level Clr spell *lesser vigor* [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 229), I'd let the initial effect benefit from the aspect—the spell healing an additional 1d8 points of damage *and* granting fast healing—but the remaining duration would grant *only* fast healing at the spell's printed rate with no increase from the aspect.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> That's not because such an effect would be particularly *powerful*—the typical Singer by the time the aspect of healing's gained is, after all, usually level 11 and can cast [*heal*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/heal.htm), for Io's sake!—but simply because that's how I'm reading the limits of the aspect. Your mileage, as always, may vary.

Comment: I agree with your opinions, but they are hardly house rules; they're very straightforward adjudications of the literal meaning of the text. Perhaps there is room for another opinion, but I nonetheless think you should present this answer as an interpretation of RAW.

Comment: @Eikre I don't use the term house rules *at all* pejoratively, and I think the term gets a bad rap. Instead, it's used here (and in every answer I write) as a synonym for *This is something that's extrapolated or gleaned from the printed text because the printed text doesn't cover it.* I admit, it's a *really strict* definition of *house rules*, but I'm okay with it because there are those who believe that *any* reading that goes beyond printed word text is, in actuality, *house rules* as another reader may read the same text differently.